# move_uploaded_file 関数で、引数の値に何を入れればよいのか分からない

Tags: php

move_uploaded_file関数を用いて画像ファイルをアップロードしたいのですが、

[PHP 画像のアップロード](https://qiita.com/ryo-futebol/items/11dea44c6b68203228ff)

このサイトを確認しても

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], './images/' . $image);
```

の `['image']['tmp_name']` にどのような値を入れればいいかわかりません。
お手数おかけしますがご教授のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 参考 [ファイルアップロードの処理](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/features.file-upload.php)

Answer (score 1):

`move_uploaded_file` に関しては一般的なコピー操作の通り、「どのファイルを」「どこに移動するか」を指定します。

[PHP: move_uploaded_file - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

> ```
> move_uploaded_file(string $from, string $to): bool
> ```

参照した記事で使用している `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` ですが、これは `$_FILES` が POST メソッドでファイルをアップロードする際に使用される特殊変数で、`['image']` の部分はフォームの `<input type="file">` の `name="***"` に指定した名前に合わせる必要があります。

> ```html
>     <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
>         <p>アップロード画像</p>
>         <input type="file" name="image">
>         <button><input type="submit" name="upload" value="送信"></button>
>     </form>
> ```

[PHP: POST メソッドによるアップロード - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

> ```html
> <!-- データのエンコード方式である enctype は、必ず以下のようにしなければなりません -->
> <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
>     <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE は、必ず "file" input フィールドより前になければなりません -->
>     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
>     <!-- input 要素の name 属性の値が、$_FILES 配列のキーになります -->
>     このファイルをアップロード: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
>     <input type="submit" value="ファイルを送信" />
> </form>
> ```
>
> ここでは、上の例のスクリプトで使われたように、 アップロードファイルの名前として userfile を 使用することを仮定していることに注意してください。 実際にはどんな名前にすることもできます。
>
> `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`
>
> アップロードされたファイルがサーバー上で保存されているテンポラリファイルの名前。